# Change session attribute value with thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to change session attribute eg. from false to true using thymleaf?

Controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class AuthorizationController {

    // some code

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(@Valid User user, HttpSession httpSession, BindingResult result, Model model) {

         // some code

         userRepository.save(user1);
         emailService.sendSimpleMessage(email, "Activation link", "" +
                "Hello, this is your activation link: https://test8205.herokuapp.com/activate?hash=" + passwordCrypt + "&user=" + name);

         httpSession.setAttribute("justRegistered", true);
         return "redirect:/clients/list";
}
```

Html template:

```
<span th:if="${session.justRegistered} == true">
    Confirm your registriatin with link delivered to your mail box.
</span>
```

After that I want to change value of "session.justRegistered" on side of template from true to false, so the message "Confirm..." wont appear again after eg. refreshing the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has a concept of a FlashAttribute which is an attribute that will persist across a redirect and automatically removes itself on the next page that is useful in situations like this.

Add `RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs` to your Post handler method params. Then in your method call 
`redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("justRegistered", true);`

It will be available on the page they are redirected to but disappear once they reload or navigate away.  Just be careful that you are not performing multiple redirections.

Comment: Great, it works, thanks! And I also changed one line in html to: <span th:if="${justRegistered} == true">